# How to keep module enabled across instances in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, configuration

is there any way to **keep free contributed plugin** *(for example MageMonkey 2)* to be enabled **across different instances of website**(dev, stage, prod), keeping the configuration?

Comment: As per I know currently we don't have mixture of this 2 commands  `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer/production` & `php bin/magento module:enable MODULE_NAME`

Comment: Thank You, for response. I can execute this commands in my CI scripts, I meant more generic way, for example to enable module in update script from other module, or extension allowing to keep configuration through instances, like features in drupal, or some hook around composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggested solution:

I've managed situation by adding required module to **composer.json** of my custom administrative module managing dependencies to another modules and adding **UpgradeData.php** with update script.

## More detailed explanation:

### Code structure

```
|--app/
   |--code/
      |--<My Vendor>/
         |-- ...
         |--<My Module>/
            |-- ...
            |--Helper
               |--Configuration.php
            |--Setup/
               |--UpgradeData.php      # save custom module settings here
            |-- ...
            |--composer.json           # module's composer file
|-- ...
|--vendor/
   |--<ContribVendor>/
      |--<ContribModule>/
|-- ...
|--composer.json                    # home directory composer file
|--auth.json                        # can be gitignored
```

### Module composer.json sample

```
{
  "name": "<My Vendor>/<My Module>",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
    "<Custom Vendor>/<Custom Module>": "<Module Version>"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "<My Module version>",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

### Upgrade script sample:

```
<?php
namespace <MyVendor>\Updates\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use <MyVendor>\<My Module>\Helper\Configuration;
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
  /**
   * @var \<MyVendor>\<My Module>\Helper\Configuration
   */
  protected $config;

  public function __construct(
      Configuration $config
  ) {
      $this->config = $config;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
   */
  public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
      $setup->startSetup();
      try {
          if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '<ModuleVersion>', '<=')) {
              $this->config->setMyModuleSettings(); # Implemented in HELPER below.
          }
      }
      catch (\Exception $e) {
          print $e->getMessage();
      }

      $setup->endSetup();
   }
 }
```

### Helper script sample:

```
<?php
namespace FFW\Updates\Helper;

use Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class Configuration extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config
   */
  protected $config;

  public function construct(
    Context $context,
    Config $config
  ) {
      parent::__construct($context);
      $this->config = $config;
  }

  /**
   * Helper to set <My Module> settings.
   */
  public function setMyModuleSettings() {
    $this->config->saveConfig('<Config key according to schema.xml of module implementing config - ContribModule in our case>', <Value>, '<Scope>', '<ScopeId>');
  }
}
```

## Final step

I my CI i run 2 steps on each deployment - during development:

```
magento setup:upgrade
magento setup:di:compile
```

### Disclaimer

**Do not forget to add your api keys for contrib module to composer auth.json file (or any other authentication method for composer).**